# Conditional sum when value negative

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I'm figuring out how to formulate a conditional statement.

If a value in a column is negative, it should add up by 86400.

Any idea?

Comment: `case_when` from `dplyr`

Comment: or `ifelse` from `base R`

Comment: Please see my answer. Next time, please share a reproducible example of your dataset. Otherwise, you may receive downvotes and most importantly people may not be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your real-word dataset is a data frame, the following will work. You need to specify the column (in this example, column `b`) and use `ifelse` to evaluate if the value is smaller than 0, if `TRUE`, add 86400, otherwise return the original value.

```
# Create an example data frame
dt <- data.frame(a = "a", b = -3:3)
dt
#   a  b
# 1 a -3
# 2 a -2
# 3 a -1
# 4 a  0
# 5 a  1
# 6 a  2
# 7 a  3

# Add 86400 to negative value in column `b`
dt$b <- ifelse(dt$b < 0, dt$b + 86400, dt$b)
dt
#   a     b
# 1 a 86397
# 2 a 86398
# 3 a 86399
# 4 a     0
# 5 a     1
# 6 a     2
# 7 a     3
```

You can also write the above code as follows.

```
dt$b <- with(dt, ifelse(b < 0, b + 86400, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
df[,'col']=df[,'col']+ifelse(df[,'col']<0,86400,0)
```